# Get all values of the given key using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

This is my array,

```
NSArray *peopleArray = @[
@{@"name":@"Albert",@"age":@"23"},
@{@"name":@"Bruce",@"age":@"25"},
@{@"name":@"Christopher",@"age":@"56"},
@{@"name":@"Hardy",@"age":@"38"},
@{@"name":@"Marlon",@"age":@"20"},
];
```

I want to get all the names in the above array, using NSPredicates.

```
NSArray *names = ;//
//Albert,Bruce,Christopher,Hardy,Marlon
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use a predicate to extract all of the names, use KVC instead:

```
NSArray *names = [peopleArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Now that you have the array of names you can use a predicate to filter it if required.